# Is a Regular Expression Faster than using .replace()

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

Would a regular expression be faster than the following Python code?

```
myStr.replace(","," ").replace("'"," ").replace("-","").replace("_","").replace("["," ").replace("]"," ")
```

Does this mean that the str is being iterated over 6 times(the number of replace() calls)? Would a regular experession be faster or is it the same algorithm/methodlogy?

What would the regular expression of this look like?

Comment: I'd recommend writing one and testing it. You might want to see timeit - http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html - to do this.

Comment: I've tested the timings of the various answers and posted the results.

Comment: Blair's included my joke answer (a one-regex solution) but not my serious answer (use **str.translate**). I've remedied that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that a regex would almost certainly be faster, but you should do a simple benchmark to find out for sure. The code you have performs the following separate steps

```
myStr.replace(","," ")
myStr.replace("'"," ")
myStr.replace("-","")
myStr.replace("_","")
myStr.replace("["," ")
myStr.replace("]"," ")
```

and could be done in two steps with regexes:

```
re.sub(r"[,'\[\]]", " ", myStr)
re.sub(r"[-_]", "", myStr)
```

Comment: -1 (a) it's equivalent to `x = myStr.replace(","," "); x = x.replace("'"," "); etc` (b) the semicolons should be right parentheses (c) the first line should start with `myStr = ` (d) you can do it in only one regex

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Please show how this can be done in a single regex?

Comment: `re.sub(r"-_]", "", myStr)` is missing the opening square bracket - it should be `re.sub(r"[-_]", "", myStr)`. Also I have done some benchmarking (see my answer) and it appears the string replacement is still faster.

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer: use `str.translate`, it's faster than any alternative available in the standard Python distribution.**

Long answer:

> Does this mean that the str is being iterated over 6 times(the number
>   of replace() calls)?

What else could it possibly mean?

> What would the regular expression of this look like?

Which part of the re docs are you having trouble with?

As an understandable equivalent, try this:

```
"".join(" " if c in ",'-_[]" else c for c in myStr)
```

or this:

```
cset = set(",'-_[]")
"".join(" " if c in cset else c for c in myStr)
```

As far as speed is concerned, you should do some timings, with data similar to what you expect to have. Don't forget to include a test where there are no such characters in your string.

*Update* Here are teh codez that actually work:

```
>>> import re
>>> myStr = "a,b'c-d_f[g]h"
>>> re.sub(r"[,'\-_[\]]", " ", myStr)
'a b c d f g h'
>>>
```

More generally, to save you from working out which characters need to be escaped, you can do this:

```
>>> badchars = ",'-_[]"
>>> regex = "[" + re.escape(badchars) + "]"
>>> print regex
[\,\'\-\_\[\]]
>>> re.sub(regex, " ", myStr)
'a b c d f g h'
>>>
```

*Update 2* To do what the OP question seems to ask for in one regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r"[,'\-_[\]]", lambda m: "" if m.group(0) in "-_" else " ", myStr)
'a b cdf g h'
```

*Update 3* To do what the OP question seems to ask for in the fastest possible manner, using `str.translate`

```
# Python 2.X
>>> myStr = "a,b'c-d_f[g]h"
>>> chars2space = ",'[]"
>>> chars2delete = "-_"
>>> table = "".join(" " if chr(i) in chars2space else chr(i) for i in xrange(256))
>>> myStr.translate(table, chars2delete)
'a b cdf g h'

# Python 3.x
>>> myStr = "a,b'c-d_f[g]h"
>>> chars2space = ",'[]"
>>> chars2delete = "-_"
>>> table = dict((ord(c), " ") for c in chars2space)
>>> table.update(dict((ord(c), None) for c in chars2delete))
>>> myStr.translate(table)
'a b cdf g h'
>>>
```

*Update 4* I have updated Blair's timer gadget to include my serious solution (str.translate). Following are the results on my no-name Intel box running standard win32 Python 2.7.2:

```
# input = "a,b'c-d_f[g]h"
String replacement         : 0.00000195 seconds per replacement ( 1.00 X)
Borodin: two-regex         : 0.00000429 seconds per replacement ( 2.20 X)
John Machin: regex/lambda  : 0.00000489 seconds per replacement ( 2.51 X)
John Machin: str.translate : 0.00000042 seconds per replacement ( 0.22 X)

# input *= 100
String replacement         : 0.00001612 seconds per replacement ( 1.00 X)
Borodin: two-regex         : 0.00015821 seconds per replacement ( 9.82 X)
John Machin: regex/lambda  : 0.00036253 seconds per replacement (22.50 X)
John Machin: str.translate : 0.00000424 seconds per replacement ( 0.26 X)

# input *= 1000
String replacement         : 0.00012404 seconds per replacement ( 1.00 X)
Borodin: two-regex         : 0.00148683 seconds per replacement (11.99 X)
John Machin: regex/lambda  : 0.00360127 seconds per replacement (29.03 X)
John Machin: str.translate : 0.00003361 seconds per replacement ( 0.27 X)

# input = "nopunctuation" * 1000 i.e. same length as previous results
String replacement         : 0.00002708 seconds per replacement ( 1.00 X)
Borodin: two-regex         : 0.00018181 seconds per replacement ( 6.71 X)
John Machin: regex/lambda  : 0.00008235 seconds per replacement ( 3.04 X)
John Machin: str.translate : 0.00001780 seconds per replacement ( 0.66 X)
```

Looks like `str.translate` is way out in front.

Comment: You have misread the OP. Underscore and hyphen are to be replaced with an empty string while comma, single-quote, and open and close bracket should result in a space.

Comment: Looked like typoes to me :-) Better solution coming up. Watch this space.

Comment: It would be easy to solve using a function for the replacement string but that would clearly impact on the performance, which was the point of the quesion.

Answer (score 4):

Out of interest, I wrote a quick timing test using `timeit` on the methods given in the other answers. The regular expressions were all pre-compiled to be on the safe side. The results on my netbook (Ubuntu 11.10, Python 2.7.2), from fastest to slowest:

```
String replacement: 8.556e-06 seconds per replacement
Borodin's two-regex solution: 1.979e-05 seconds per replacement
John Machin's regex/lambda solution: 2.623e-05 seconds per replacement
```

So the two-regex solution is 2.3 times slower than simple string replacement, and John Machin's single-regex and lambda-function solution is 3.06 times slower than string replacement.

To test with a longer string, I concatenated the original string 100 times:

```
String replacement: 7.600e-05 seconds per replacement
Borodin's two-regex solution: 7.894e-04 seconds per replacement
John Machin's regex/lambda solution: 1.909e-03 seconds per replacement
```

Two-regex is 10 times slower than string replacement, and regex/lambda 25 times slower.

And then concatenating the original input 1000 times:

```
String replacement: 5.396e-04 seconds per replacement
Borodin's two-regex solution: 8.584e-03 seconds per replacement
John Machin's regex/lambda solution: 2.094e-02 seconds per replacement
```

Two-regex is now 15.9 times slower than string replacement, and regex/lambda 38.8 times slower.

It seems as the input gets longer the regular expressions get slower and slower in comparison. I assume this is because the regular expressions also have to scan through the input character by character, and obviously the more complicated tests they perform is slower than looping over it several times. Using the lambda function to replace the characters with a single regex seems to be considerably slower than using two regexes.

The code for anybody else who wants to check the timings on their machine:

```
import sys
import timeit

# How many times to test each method.
n = 1000

# String to test with.
test_str = "a,b'c-d_f[g]h"

# Correct output.
correct = "a b cdf g h"

# Uncomment to try longer strings.
#test_str *= 100
#correct *= 100

# Setup code (i.e., code which shouldn't be included in the timings).
setup = """
import re

# Borodin's two-regex solution.
bre1 = re.compile(r"[,'\[\]]")
bre2 = re.compile(r"[-_]")

# John Machin's solution.
jmre = re.compile(r"[,'\-_[\]]")
repl = lambda m: "" if m.group(0) in "-_" else " "

test_str=\"{0:s}\"""".format(test_str)

# The methods.
methods = {
    'String replacement': 'result=test_str.replace(","," ").replace("\'"," ").replace("-","").replace("_","").replace("["," ").replace("]"," ")',
    'Borodin\'s two-regex solution': 'result=bre2.sub("", bre1.sub(" ", test_str))',
    'John Machin\'s regex/lambda solution': 'result=jmre.sub(repl, test_str)',
}

# Execute the setup so we can test for correctness.
exec(setup)

for method, code in methods.items():
    # Check the code gives correct results.
    exec(code)
    if(result != correct):
        sys.stdout.write('{0} gave incorrect output: {1}\n'.format(method, result))
        continue

    # Time it.
    t = timeit.timeit(code, setup, number=n)
    sys.stdout.write('{0}: {1:.3e} seconds per replacement\n'.format(method, t/n))
```

Comment: I have included my serious answer (str.translate) and tidied up your output. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The regexes would probably be faster. A good regex engine (and Python has a good one) is a very fast way to do the sorts of string transformations it can handle. Unless you're really good with regexes though, it will be a bit harder to understand.

Generally, when you're first writing a project you should optimise for programmer time (i.e. your time), not runtime. The time you spend thinking about whether two regex calls is faster than 6 replace calls could be better spent writing more code.

If this question was prompted because you got your program done(ish) and started running it, and found that it was too slow, then now is a good time to be thinking about these things, although you will probably need to make a bunch of performance measurements to find out where the runtime is being spent. It's very likely that most of the runtime in your program is being spent in relatively small sections of your code, so once you can identify them you can concentrate on making them faster. And my intuition is that these replace calls are not such a location. But even very experienced programmers are notoriously bad at predicting where the "hotspots" in their code are as its being written.

If, OTOH, this question was prompted because you had just written the replace calls and were wondering if maybe you could do it in a way that runs faster, you should probably just move on and write more code. That's the fun bit of programming, after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

I belive, in this case, regular expression will be faster, because you really have to iterate over whole string each time, when using `replace`.